# @Aspect cannot be resolved to a type in spring aop. iam using jdk 1.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-annotations

[code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXjeA.png)

you can find the code and error in the first image. and libraries in the second image.[libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41QGj.png)

Comment: spring-aop has lots of dependencies. To resolve them automatically use Maven. Here is example of spring aspects https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding **aspectjrt.jar** and **aspectjweaver.jar**. just download these two and add.